# Multiple File Upload on a single button click

Tags: c#

I have added AJAX Controls. Is it possible to upload multiple files using "AsyncFileUpload" control ? If so, how will you do it ? If not, is there any third party multiple file upload controls to be used in ASP.Net using C# ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=317)

it uses jquery to upload multiple files to the server.